# search by multiple values using checkbox in laravel

Tags: laravel, search, checkbox, multiple-select

I have `job_sector` table in which `sector_id` and `job_id` fields are there. I just want to search `job_id` by the `sectors` which I have selected through checkbox. One may select multiple sectors.

My model :

```
public function scopeSelectedOptions($query, $input = [])
{
    if(!empty($input)) {
        if(array_key_exists('sector_id', $input)) {
            $query->whereHas('sector_id', function($q) use ($input) {
                return $q->whereIn('sector_id', $input['sector_id']);
            });
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Controller :

```
public function jobsFilter(Request $request)
{
    $jobs = JobSector::SelectedOptions(request()->all())->get();
    return view('front.pages.job.jobfilter')->with(['title'=>'Job Filter', 'jobs' => $jobs]);           
}
```

Form from where I am selecting multiple sectors :

```
<form action="{{ route('job.jobfilter') }}" method="GET" class="mb-4">
  {{csrf_field()}}                      
    @foreach(get_sectors() as $k=>$s)                     
      <input type="checkbox" name="input[]" value="{{ $k }}">{{ $k }}<br>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Query showing the output :

```
@foreach($jobs as $c)
    {{ $c->job_id }} <br>
  @endforeach
```

It shows me all the job_id in the table.

Please help me out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the wrong array to your scope

it would look like this :

```
['input' => ['12' => true]]
```

try this

```
<form action="{{ route('job.jobfilter') }}" method="GET" class="mb-4">
  {{csrf_field()}}                      
    @foreach(get_sectors() as $k=>$s)                     
      <input type="checkbox" name="sector_id[{{ $k }}]">{{ $k }}<br>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

```
public function jobsFilter(Request $request)
{
    $jobs = JobSector::whereIn('sector_id', array_keys(request()->sector_id))->get();
    return view('front.pages.job.jobfilter')->with(['title'=>'Job Filter', 'jobs' => $jobs]);           
}
```

(I just ignore your scope to be more readable)

Comment: ok, but whenever I search after checking the checkbox, its search by sector_id 1 only.

Comment: I mess with the HTML code, a checkbox have no "value" attribute, it is juste 1 or not even sent in the payload, I edited my answer

Comment: in your controller try to `dd(request()->all())` and are you sure your get_sectors() function work correctly ?